# Kafka Microservice Proper Use Cases

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In my new work's project, i discovered that instead of directly making post/put API calls from one microservice to another microservice, a microservice would produce a message to kafka, which is then consumed by a single microservice.

For example, Order microservice would publish a record to "pending-order" topic, which would then be consumed by Inventory microservice (no other consumer). In turn, after consuming the record and done some processing, Inventory microservice would produce a record to "processed-order" which would then be consumed only by Order microservice.

Is this a correct use case? Or is it better to just do API calls between microservices in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There are two strong use cases of Kafka in a microservice based application:

1. You need to do a state change in multiple microservices as part of a single end user activity. If you do this by calling all the appropriate microservice APIs sequentially or parallely, there will be two issues:
   Firstly, you lose atomicity i.e. you canNot guarantee "all or nothing" . It's very well possible that the call to microservice A succeeds but call to service B fails and that would lead to inconsistent data permanently. Secondly, in a cloud environment unpredictable latency and network timeouts are not uncommon and so when you make multiple calls as part of a single call, the probability of one of these calls getting delayed or failed is higher impacting user experience. Hence, the general recommendation here is, you write the user action atomically in a Kafka topic as an event and have multiple consumer groups - one for each interested microservice consume the event and make the state change in their own database. If the action is triggered by the user from a UI, you would also need to provide a "read your own write" guarantee where the user would like to see his data immediately after writing. Therefore, you'd need to write the event first in the local database of the first microservice and then do log based [event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) (using an aporopriate Kafka Connector) to transfer the event data to Kafka. This will enable you to show the data to the user from the local DB. You may also need to update a cache, a search index, a distributed file system etc. and all of these can be done by consuming the Kafka events published by the individual microservices.
2. It is not very uncommon that you need to pull data from multiple microservice to do some activity or to aggregate data and display to the user. This, in general, is not recommended because of the latency and timeout issue mentioned above. It is usually recommended that we precompute those aggregates in the microservice local DB based on Kafka events published by the other microservices when they were changing their own state. This will allow you to serve the aggregate data to the user much faster. This is called [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view) pattern.

The only point to remember here is writing to Kafka log or broker and reading from it us asynchronous and there maybe a little time delay.

Comment: yes so it is obvious that if there are multiple consumer listening to a topic, the use case makes sense. But i was referring to a case where there are only 2 parties involved, one producing a message, another is consuming it and doing action which later caused it to produce message which will be again consumed by the first party

Answer (score -1):

Microservice as consumer, seems fishy to me. You might mean Listeners to that topic would consume the message and maybe they will call your second microservice i.e. Inventory Microservice.

Yes, the model is fine, specially when you want to have asynchronous behavior and loads of traffic handled through it.

Imaging a scenario when you have more than 1 microservice to call from 1 endpoint. Here you need either aggregation layer which aggregates your services and you call it once, or you would like to publish several messages to Kafka which then will do the job.

Also think about Read services, if you need to call a microservice to read some data from somewhere else, then you can't use Kafka.

It all depends on your requirements and design.